# Set Background Image in Div Without Separate CSS

Tags: html, css

To create a background image in a div, you can easily write

```
<style type="text/css">
.bgimg {
    background-image: url('../images/divbg.png');
}
</style>

...

<div class="bgimg">
    div with background
</div>
```

I would like to do this without a seperate style sheet. It might look something like

```
<div class="bgimg" background-image="url('../images/divbg.png')">
     div with background
</div>
```

However, when I try this, it doesn't work. Is setting a background image in a div without separate CSS possible?

Comment: CSS file - best, `Style` tags - bad, `style` attribute - worst.

Comment: Type [apply background image to div](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=gg0tWY_VO4TT8gf_zKyIBA&gws_rd=ssl#q=apply+background+image+to+div) and you'll get tons of answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the style element:

```
<div class="bgimg" style="background-image: url('../images/divbg.png')"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `background-image` in `style` tag. Also you have to set `width` & `height` for properly working.

```html
<div class="bgimg" style="background-image:url(https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff&text=Background+Image); width: 200px; height: 200px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods of doing this and you can use other of the two:

```
<div class="bgimg" style="background-image:url('../images/divbg.png');">
</div>
```

or you can use

```
<div class="bgimg" style="background:url('../images/divbg.png');">
</div>
```

To see the background don't forget to put in content to your div.

Run the below code to see it work:

```css
.bgimg{height:328px; width:328px;}
```

```html
    <div class="bgimg" style="background-image:url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/89aa49add7f84c840f2d011857353431?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1);">
    </div>
    <br/ ><br/ ><br/ ><br/ >
    <div class="bgimg" style="background:url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/89aa49add7f84c840f2d011857353431?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1');">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use inline style using style attribute inside of your div element. Like this:

```
<div style="background-image: url('../images/divbg.png')"></div>
```

Note that you may have to remove apostrophes in the url() to make it work in Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the background image with inline CSS and eliminate the need of a seperate css block or file:

```
 <div style="background-image: url('../images/divbg.png')"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using **jQuery** you can do this on `document.ready`:

**Still.. using CSS is recomended**

Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.bgimg[background-image]').each(function() {
    $(this).css('background-image', $(this).attr('background-image'));
  })
})
```

```css
.bgimg {
  min-height: 100px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bgimg" background-image="url('http://lorempixel.com/400/100/?0')">
  div with background
</div>
<div class="bgimg" background-image="url('http://lorempixel.com/400/100/?1')">
  div with background
</div>
<div class="bgimg" background-image="url('http://lorempixel.com/400/100/?2')">
  div with background
</div>
```